# include и except используя гем Oj

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Решил перейти на гем `Oj` для отправки `json` для клиента. Но заметил что не происходит добавление в `json` данных с другой модели.

Пример кода:

```
render json: @link, :include => [:comments], :except => [:updated_at]
```

**без `Oj`:**

[image]

**c `Oj`:**

[image]

и метод `render` в `Api::BaseApiController`

```
class Api::BaseApiController < ApplicationController
  abstract!
  private

  def render(options={})
    self.status = options[:status] || 200
    self.content_type = 'application/json'
    body = Oj.dump(options[:json], mode: :compat)
    self.headers['Content-Length'] = body.bytesize.to_s
    self.response_body = body
  end
  ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller, self)
end
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Comment: А этот метод `render` откуда взялся?

Comment: я написал в своем классе. Щас обновлю код в вопросе

Comment: Ну, этот код игнорирует все опции, которые вы передаёте в рендер, кроме `:json` и `:status`. С чего бы ему учитывать другие?

Comment: Вам скорее всего хватит просто гема `oj_mimic_json`, который маскирует Oj под `JSON` из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: `oj_mimic_json` используется на пару с `oj` ?

Comment: Ага. По неведомым мне причинам, `oj` у него в зависимостях отсутствует, так что приходится указывать явно. Но учитывая то, что гем состоит из одной строчки, можно просто эту строчку поместить в какой-нибудь initializer.